# React useReducer conditional dispatch

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer

I am trying to implement a "use company address" button that autofills the inputs if selected.

I get the pre-filled values as expected, however when I hit submit, the data for these fields are blank/didn't update.

My Code:

```
            <AdvancedInput
            name="street"
            type="text"
            value={useCompAddr ? companyAddress?.street : state.street}
            onChange={(e) =>
              dispatch({ field: "street", payload: e.target.value })
            }
          />
```

It does work when I click in each input field before submitting.

Any help is much appreciated

EDIT
The fields in question look like so;

```
switch(action.payload) {
case "street":
... rest of fields
  return {
    ...state, [action.field]: action.payload
}
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code of the reducer?

Comment: @BhaveshDaswani pretty standard resolver, see edit for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone reads this. The issue was the state was not being set before the onChange was triggered.

```
    value={
useCompAddr ? (state.street = companyAddress?.street) : state.street } onChange={(e) => dispatch({ field: "street", payload: e.target.value }) }
```

was the solution.